# mobile - developing a sip client

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, titanium

Hy , I need to build a cross platform mobile app (iphone, android) , to read a user phone no or imsi , call a web service to auth it and then let the user to be able to call any number (not voip, real number) from the program interface using sip . I already have the server to do this but i don;t know how to implement it.

I read that appcelerator's titanium doesn't have support for SIP protocol. Is this protocol implemented in some SDK's ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org), it has also iPhone support.

Comment: However it's quite a pain to develop a SIP client for mobile phones because of different constraints. If you need the *solution* you make consider licensing one. Let me make some modest advertisement: check out PrivateGSM from [PrivateWave](http://www.privatewave.com). It has everything that you described and they are ready to license their app (even rebranded) to you. You can download their demo app from the app stores.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in titanium. There may be some modules, but for something that complex, I really don't recommend Titanium.
You should make two natives applications : you will have more choices, and more validated solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad TITANIUM does not have modules like this .